# Count number of li(s) and set their width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set dynamic width to li(s) based on how many li(s) are there in list. For example if there are 18 li(s). Each width should be 100% / 18 = 5.55%. What if I would have 3 different sets of li(s). I tried to use this. but it's not working

```
$('.lesson-nav ul li').width( 100 / $(".lesson-nav ul li").length );
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `%` sign in your width, jQuery defaults to pixels.

```
$('.lesson-nav ul li').width( 100 / $(".lesson-nav ul li").length + '%' );
```

Comment: For unknown reason: This script gives width 120% while there is only 1 li and 27.55% when there are 18 lis.

Also this answer does not address if there are more than 1 UL inside .lesson-nav.

Answer (score 1):

Your code would definitely give you width in pixels. Try this out:

```
$('.lesson-nav ul li').width( ( 100 / $(".lesson-nav ul li").length ) + '%' );
```

UPDATED: furthermore try out **inline-block** for every **li** element.

Comment: Well, I assume you've set li's to be inline instead of block-level elements otherwise this topic would not have had much sense.
However and AFAIR that's not how CSS width works. Try out **inline-block** for every **li** element.

Comment: Exactly same problem goes here ( as I replied to Barmar ).

Comment: That's weird. Could you please show your HTML code? With and without multiple ul's.